# How to fix these 404 errors in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

So, I've been looking for a way to sort out these 404 errors on a WordPress site. This log is compiled using the Redirection plugin for WP. Anyway, how would you go about sorting out these 404 errors? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

So, these mostly appear to be bots scraping the site (atleast it appears that way from the User Agent Info.) Where are they getting these URL's?

[image: WP 404 Errors Log]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do you can redirect these links to the home page best way to make it SEO friendly there are so many ways you can archive this by adding code in htaccess or this plugin can be most useful in this issue:

[All 404 Redirect to Homepage](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-404-redirect-to-homepage/)

[Redirect 404 Error Page to Homepage or Custom Page with Logs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-404-error-page-to-homepage-or-custom-page/)